# Is there a way to make asking multiple if statements more succinct?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, python-3.10

I wanted to make a pretty simple program where it picks from a random list (I decided to use fruits) without showing the user, and gives hints about what fruit is picked like what color the fruit is, until the user provides the correct answer, I tried to wright it in a way that asks 'if the correct answer is a yellow fruit, print "the fruit is yellow"' with it checking if the correct answer matches any of from a list of fruits. I already know a way to implement this properly but I feel like there must be some more efficient way to resolve my problem that I am missing.

this was my first attempt, it obviously didn't work it just takes the first if statement and treats every item from the fruit list as correct for some reason. I know I can make this work by repeating ''' if correct == "item" or ''' for every individual item on the list that is applicable, but I feel like there must be some simpler solution that I'm overlooking or don't know because of inexperience. like somehow storing all applicable items in a list and somehow applying the if statement as a blanket to each individual item in the list.

```
import random
fruit = ["apple","banana","cherry","durian","lemon","orange","pineapple","watermelon"]
max = len(fruit)
rng = (random.randint(0,max-1))
correct = (fruit[rng])
if correct == "apple" or "cherry":
    print("red")
elif correct == "banana" or "lemon" or "pineapple":
    print("yellow")

print(fruit[rng])
```

This is it working as intended, the colors match the fruits, my concern is if I apply this method to a larger list it will be very ugly and tedious.

```
import random
fruit = ["apple","banana","cherry","durian","lemon","orange","pineapple","watermelon"]
max = len(fruit)
rng = (random.randint(0,max-1))
correct = (fruit[rng])
if correct == "apple" or correct == "cherry":
    print("red")
elif correct == "banana" or correct == "lemon" or correct == "pineapple":
    print("yellow")

print(fruit[rng])
```

I only have it printing the correct answer to check if it's working properly for now.

Comment: `if correct in fruit`

Comment: 1) Have  a look into `random.choice`.  2) Using a `dict` to store the fruits and colours.  These two changes would help make the code more succinct.

Comment: @QWERTYL - No, as that’s membership test, not a specific colour test as the OP requires.

Comment: The first one fails because `"cherry"` is a non-empty string, so even if `correct == "apple"` is false, `"cherry"` is considered true. (To be clear: the comparison `correct == "cherry"` is not made.)

Comment: `if correct in ('banana', 'lemon', 'pineapple'):`

Answer (score 1):

Group them by color with a dictionary:

```py
fruits = {
    'cherry': 'red',
    'apple': 'red',
    'banana': 'yellow',
    ...
}

color = fruits.get(correct, 'Invalid')

# or

try:
    color = fruits[correct]
except KeyError:
    print("Invalid")
    raise
```